# Is there a convention for distinguishing different types of inequalities?

Tags: inequality, soft-question, terminology, article-writing, convention

I'm trying to describe a set of inequalities I have in such a way that it's clear what I'm referring to without actually restating them all (I have $27$), and I realized I don't know of a standard convention (or at least can't recall it at present).  For example, when we have two statements such as

$$x_{1} = x_{2}, \quad x_{3} \le x_{4}$$

it's clear to refer to the first as an equality and the second as an inequality.  If we expand this to something like

$$x_{1} = x_{2},\quad x_{3}\le x_{4},\quad x_{5} < x_{6}$$

we can refer to these as  an equality, an inequality that is not strict, and a strict inequality, respectively.  It's a bit cumbersome, but it communicates the point.  What's the convention for referring to something like

$$x_{1} = x_{2},\quad x_{3}\le x_{4},\quad x_{5} < x_{6}, \quad x_{7} \neq x_{8} ?$$

In particular, what's the convention for referring to inequalities of the form $a\neq b$ when other types of inequalities are present so as to avoid ambiguity?